# Reopen queue dialog is broken on second level, shows popup "You must select a reason before submitting." when a reason is selected

Tags: bug, review-queues

The reopen review queue dialog seems to be broken. Steps to reproduce:

1. Review reopen votes: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen
2. Select *"Leave closed"* and click *"Submit"*
3. Select *"This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline."*
4. Select a reason (e.g. *"Needs debugging details"*)
5. Click *"Keep closed"*

Expected behaviour:
Vote to keep closed is recorded

Actual behaviour:
Error popup shows up with message: *"You must select a reason before submitting."*

[image: A screenshot with a popup with message: "You must select a reason before submitting", and keep closed dialog with "Needs debugging details" selected]

Selecting any 'keep closed' reason other than *"This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline."* in the top-level dialog will record the keep closed vote as expected.

As far as I can recall, this behaviour started yesterday (8th of December).

Comment: Bug has been reported already, see the other question.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow overlooked that one, and it didn't popup when writing the question.